# Drag a <div> and on drop unhide a hidden <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issues using the Drag and Drop in jQuery. I have multiple 'buttons' that i want to effect other divs visible properties. (so drag something onto an area to un hide things)

I cant seem to get it working, anyone got any pointers?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#btn_IncCat').draggable({
    containment: '#content',
    cursor: 'move',
    snap: '#content',
    revert: true,
    revertDuration: 900,
    opacity: 0.35,

});


$('#MobSelection').droppable({
    accept: '.btn',
    drop: function (ev, ui) {
        ui.draggable.hide(1000);
        ui.draggable.addClass('dropped');
        drop: $('#btn_IncCat').on("drop", function (event, ui) {
            $('#IncidentCatSearch').removeClass('hidden');
        })
    }
})
```

});

Above is the jQuery i'm trying to get working. Here is a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbnyof56/1/) of an example. Any pointers would be appreciated. I know that they cant be 'buttons' to work with drag and drop so i will change the HTML to normal divs but styled to looked differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you would like to achieve, but based on your description, I would use sortable with connected lists and something like this would work: [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqjte801/2/). Hope this helps. Good luck!

JS:

```
$( ".row, #MobSelection" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".well",
  stop: function (ev, ui) {
        $('#IncidentCatSearch').removeClass('hidden');
  }
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Thanks, ill have a play with it. I have multiple hidden fields and i want the user to drag and drop onto an area what elements they want to use.

Comment: Kinda makes sense. In that case you can use the ui variable of the stop function to decide what appears on which item's drop.

Comment: I think i'm being thick. How would i differentiate between Category and Number for example? So dragging Number would unhide the hidden number element and dragging category would unhide the hidden category element.

Comment: You can use the ui.item object and grab the id of it. Similarly, you can use classes to group more of them together (e.g. the .btn-primary and .btn-success classes you defined would behave differently). I updated the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bqjte801/3/). Also, refer to the jQuery UI documentation of the stop event [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop) . Hope it helps.

Comment: @MikeHughes, if this sorted your issue, could you mark it as a solution, please?